# Nested class design C++ virtual

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, wxwidgets

I have a design problem in my application. I am quite new to the concept of virtual methods, inheritance and so forth & can't get it to run properly.

This is the situation:

I have a class called UI_Brainwash (pure coincidence) in which I have nested a second class SoundReciver.

```
class UI_BRAINWASH : public wxDialog
{
public:
    UI_BRAINWASH(wxWindow* parent,const wxString& title,double sec);
    virtual ~UI_BRAINWASH();

    void OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event);      
    void StartLoop();

    class Soundreciver : public irrklang::ISoundStopEventReceiver
    {
                Soundreciver();
        // why is this not allowed?!
                Soundreciver(UI_BRAINWASH* par){this->parent = par;}
        virtual void OnSoundStopped(ISound* sound, E_STOP_EVENT_CAUSE reason, void* userData);

    public: // or private: doesn't change it -> compiler still complains
        UI_BRAINWASH* parent;

    };

private:
    wxTimer* m_timer;
```

Inside my Brainwash class I play a sound and once the sound has been played OnSoundStopped() is called, which is a virtual method of the abstract irrklang::ISoundStopEventReceiver Class.

http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/docu/classirrklang_1_1_i_sound_stop_event_receiver.html

In that method I would like to start a wxTimer which is a member of the UI_Brainwash class, the problem is I can't access the variables of the class without having a handle to it (or can i ?) so I thought of writing a constructor:

Soundreciver(UI_BRAINWASH* par){this->parent = par;}

but when I compile that with VC2008 I get the following error:

UI_BRAINWASH::Soundreciver::Soundreciver' : cannot access private member declared in class 'UI_BRAINWASH::Soundreciver'
: see declaration of 'UI_BRAINWASH::Soundreciver::Soundreciver'
: see declaration of 'UI_BRAINWASH::Soundreciver'

How do I solve this conundrum?

Thank you for your time / suggestions

Comment: The problem is on the constructor of your "SoundReceiver" which is private. You should set it to public. No visibility set for a class means private.

Answer (score 2):

The message you got is not the message about accessing private variable `parent`, but about accessing the constructor of the `Soundreceiver`. You need to make your `Soundreceiver` constructors public.

```
class Soundreciver : public irrklang::ISoundStopEventReceiver
{
 public:
    Soundreciver();
    // why is this not allowed?!
    Soundreciver(UI_BRAINWASH* par){this->parent = par;}
    virtual void OnSoundStopped(ISound* sound, E_STOP_EVENT_CAUSE reason, void* userData);

 private: // or private: doesn't change it -> compiler still complains
    UI_BRAINWASH* parent;

};
```

Other way would be to declare `UI_BRAINWASH` `friend` of the `Soundreciver` class, as [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405725/vlad-lazarenko) pointed out.

Comment: So it was that simple... I always thought public: would be standard -> apparently I was wrong. thank you

Comment: @AndreasGoetze `public` is default access level in `struct`. In `class`, it is `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes can access non-public members of their parents but parents cannot access children's non-public members. There are only a few ways to fix it, really. Change protection level for members you want to access (i.e. do not make `Soundreciver()` and `OnSoundStopped()` all of the sudden become private). Or use [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/friend) keyword to allow access to non-public members for certain classes and/or functions.